# SQlite - iPhone sdk - Assertion Failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to save values in SQLite Database in iPhone sdk. When I execute this line

```
[database executeNonQuery:strQuery1];
```

This message is printed on the console.

> SQLite Step Failed: constraint failed

Here's brief Header file info. I have declared it in my View Controller Header using this line.

```
Sqlite *database;
```

And here's the header of SQlite

```
@interface Sqlite : NSObject 
{
  NSInteger busyRetryTimeout;
  NSString *filePath;
  sqlite3 *_db;
}

@property (readwrite) NSInteger busyRetryTimeout;
@property (readonly) NSString *filePath;
+ (NSString *)createUuid;
+ (NSString *)version;
- (id)initWithFile:(NSString *)filePath;
- (BOOL)open:(NSString *)filePath;
- (void)close;
- (NSInteger)errorCode;
- (NSString *)errorMessage;
- (NSArray *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql, ...;
- (NSArray *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql arguments:(NSArray *)args;
- (BOOL)executeNonQuery:(NSString *)sql, ...;
- (BOOL)executeNonQuery:(NSString *)sql arguments:(NSArray *)args;
- (BOOL)commit;
- (BOOL)rollback;
- (BOOL)beginTransaction;
- (BOOL)beginDeferredTransaction;
```

Comment: What is the query you're executing? Please `NSLog(@"Query: %@",strQuery1);` right before or after that first line, and share the output here.

Comment: @mvds I have checked it in SQLite Manager and it is executing perfectly.

Comment: There is no [mcve] here, so I will try to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only there was some sort of [on line resource where you could go and enter "constraint failed" in a search box](http://www.sqlite.org/search?q=constraint+failed) to get the answer.

Since that is sadly not the case, I'll tell you.  The problem is most likely that you are violating a key constraint with your query. It's hard to say without seeing the query and the database schema, but you might be, for instance, trying to insert a row with a duplicate primary  key or insert a row with a foreign key that does not exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Thank u so much , after checking all the rest of the code i also doubt the problem is with the query. Strange thing is i printed the query onto console and executed it in the SQLite Manager and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Executing it in the SQLliteManager won't help you, it's a bit different on the iPhone. You should be able to get an error from the Database using the errorMessage property. And yes, also give us the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the mystery query isn't an `INSERT` query, and are you sure it isn't executed *twice* by your mystery code?

That would explain that you're not seeing an error when executing the query (once) manually.

Comment: The solution was same as JeremyP explained. I was adding a row and a column had duplicate value as that the rows before it. I re designed the schema and removed UNIQUE contraint from it.